# Making a VB form noninteractive in the background

Tags: vb.net, forms, interaction

I want my current "home form" to stay in the background when I click on a button which in turn opens another form on top of it.

I want something like this:
Home -> Click Button -> open new form -> New form becomes the focus of the app
                     -> Home form stays in the background

The home form should still be there, but I can't click on it or anything. When I click on the app, only the new form opened should be interactive.

Comment: You'll have to stop using a Button control if this is what you want.  Because making a window non-interactive like that does make it, you know, non-interactive and would prevent the button's Click event from getting raised.  Not that you could, Button ensures it stays interactive and always gets its owner activated.  You fake a button by drawing an image of a button.  And you have to override the ShowWithoutActivation property and wrangle WndProc() to intercept WM_MOUSEACTIVATE.  Lots of good reasons to not do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use [Form.ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to show the form as a modal dialog box.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!